# Java Tipification

Tags: java, mvp

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class _AbstractModel {}

public abstract class _AbstractPresenter<V extends _AbstractView<?>, M extends _AbstractModel> {}

public abstract class _AbstractView<P extends _AbstractPresenter<?, ?>> {}
```

How can I write:

```
public abstract class _AbstractModel {}

public abstract class _AbstractPresenter<V extends _AbstractView<P extends this>, M extends _AbstractModel> {}

public abstract class _AbstractView<P extends _AbstractPresenter<V extends this, M extends _AbstractModel>> {}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Generics allow "recursive" references:

```
public abstract class _AbstractModel {}
public abstract class _AbstractPresenter<V extends _AbstractView<P extends _AbstractPresenter<V, M>>, M extends _AbstractModel> {}
public abstract class _AbstractView<P extends _AbstractPresenter<V extends _AbstractView<P>, M extends _AbstractModel>> {}
```

Comment: This is the correct way, and Enums are specified like this. Unfortunately, there's no way to lose the extra type in the generic specification (unlike C++, a type can have extra typedefs).